# Using "disable" as a noun

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

It seems the noun derived from the verb "[disable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disable)" is **disablement**.

"[**Disablement time**](http://www.google.com/#q=%22the+disablement+time%22)" or "disablement duration" sounds a little awkward to me though. "[**Disable time**](http://www.google.com/#q=%22the+disable+time%22)" sounds better, and also gives much more Google hits. But would you say that is correct or acceptable? How about "disabling time"?

(Or is my question misworded; are you even supposed to use a noun in such context?)

Background: I'm trying to decide the name of a setting that specifies the time for which a certain software functionality is disabled.

Comment: Maybe *disability time* ...

Comment: Duration, or time until this state starts, or time at which this state starts?

Answer (score 4):

Both [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disable) and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disable) only mention *disable* as a verb.

After seeing the background you provided, I would go with [*idle time*](http://www.answers.com/topic/idle-time) ([898,000 Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22idle+time%22) vs 36,000 hits for *disable time*). The Business Dictionary [suggests](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/idle-time.html) *waiting time* as an alternative.

**Edit:** as pointed out in the comments by Kosmonaut and Bruno, yet another alternative would be *disabled time* or perhaps *time disabled* (with a participle rather than the infinitive form).

Comment: These are good.  Also, you could go with "disabled time" or even "time disabled".

Comment: Thanks. "Idle time" doesn't fit my particular case though. (But it got me thinking about alternative ways to put it; I might go with "bypass time", as it's about disabling a kind of blocking feature.)

Comment: "Idle time" may sound like the total time that the functionality was not being used, but not necessarily disabled. I think "disabled time" is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it does sound better; but, naturally, *disable* is  used as a verb. Hence "disable time" suggests that a subject is trying to disable time (whatever that means).

According to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disable  **disable** can NOT be used as a noun in formal English.

Comment: The dictionary also DOES list *disablement*, and everyone seems to agree it is awkward and ill-suited for this context.  So, I am not sure that formal English rules are what we should focus on.